# Documentation for PopupBasherConfiguration?

Tags: c#, excel, hpc

I'm using the HPC Excel Driver, and need to resolve this error found in the event log (with actual message removed):

> Popup window 'Microsoft Excel' may be blocking job progress. Consider
>   changing your workbook to remove this popup or configuring popup
>   bashing to automatically dismiss it. Window Message: '---- (the
>   message) ----' Window Class: '#32770'

I have added this to my code, but it isn't effective.

```
var configuration = new PopupBasherConfiguration
{
  Period = 500
};
```

I have not found any documentation about this object or how to use it. It should be documented here: [Microsoft.Hpc.Excel Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hpc.excel%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but there is no mention of it, or how to "configure popup bashing" as hinted at in the error message.

Any suggestions?

Any reference documents that talk about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found some documentation... the HPC SDK has some sample applications. In two of them ("xlcmd" and "HelloWorldService"), the `app.config`/`program.config` file has lots of comments that provide the documentation.

Without all the comments, here's what is needed in the `.config` file:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="PopupBasherConfiguration"
     type="Microsoft.Hpc.Excel.PopupBasherSectionHandler,Microsoft.Hpc.Excel,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     allowDefinition="Everywhere"
     allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication"
     />
</configSections>
```

And further down in the `.config` file:

```
<PopupBasherConfiguration Period="1000">
    <Windows>
      <!-- This rule matches the VBA MsgBox dialog. 
           Every time this pops up, this rule pushes the Ok button. -->
      <Window Title="Microsoft Excel" Class="#32770">
        <Child Title="Ok" Role="ROLE_SYSTEM_PUSHBUTTON" Action="DoDefault" Search="Exact" />
      </Window>
    </Windows>
</PopupBasherConfiguration>
```